# T1 vs LY1 behavior of lstlistings

Tags: listings, font-encodings

I am writing a document with listings in it, which are typeset in Courier. When I changed the main font of the document, the package for this font (installed with `autoinst`) decided that it should switch the main font encoding from T1 to LY1. To my surprise, this affected the typesetting of my listings.

I've stripped down the document to a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[<<font encoding>>]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
print "Hello world"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

With `<<font encoding>>` set to `T1`, this compiles to:

[image]

With `<<font encoding>>` set to `LY1`, this compiles to:

[image]

Note the different letter spacing. The problem does not seem to show up when using the Courier font outside of the `lstlisting` environment, e.g., `\texttt{Hello}`.

I have solved the problem by explicitly choosing the font encoding `T1` in `\lstset`. But it still leaves me puzzled why this happened in the first place. So, I have a two-part question:

1. The package created by `autoinst` explicitly supports both `T1` and `LY1`, i.e., it has a command `\RequirePackage[T1,LY1]{fontenc}`. Then, why does it select `LY1` despite the explicit `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` command in my document?
2. Why do the two font encodings give different results when used in a listing?

Comment: You should better make a new question regarding question 1 (with an example).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I was thinking the same; however, the font I'm using is proprietary, so I can't do that. While I was writing the question I thought that maybe I should move the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` *after* the package for the font. (Note that I fixed a mistake in my original formulation of the question: the font package has the command  `\RequirePackage[T1,LY1]{fontenc}`, i.e., *LY1* was missing previously.)

Comment: I can't think of any reason to use LY1 encoding. I wrote those LY1 encoding files to use a custom encoding required by the Y&Y TeX system which is no longer distributed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree. I never asked for the LY1 encoding, but I can't seem to disable it. The font package (installed through `autoinst`) just selects it for me.

Comment: can't you edit the package and remove LY1 or anyway you can put `\fontecoding{T1}\selectfont` after the package to get the document back to T1.

Comment: You can choose for which encodings autoinst creates supporting files and which is the default, see `texdoc autoinst`. Beside this it is naturally possible to reset and redefine the default encoding: `\renewcommand\encodingdefault{T1}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metrics for `pcr` in the T1 and in LY1 encodings are different: this diagnostic document will

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont \showthe\dimexpr1em\relax
\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont \showthe\dimexpr1em\relax

\stop
```

will stop twice with the messages

```
> 10.0pt.
```

and

```
> 11.99998pt.
```

If you type `qcr` instead of `pcr`, so loading TeX Gyre Cursor that's a clone of Courier, you get 11.99998pt in both cases.

Further research shows that the em is 10pt wide for `pcr` also in the OT1 encoding, while it is 11.99998pt for `qcr`.

What's the correct value? Probably 12pt (note that 11.99998pt is just one scaled point less), because the (fixed) character width is 6pt.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the `column=fixed` setting and there the spacing depends on the value of `em` which is different between the two encodings (it would be interesting to know why ...) as pointed out by egreg. If you use an absolute length to define the width of the characters you get an uniform spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont,}

\begin{document}
\lstset{basewidth={3mm,0.45em}} %3mm box width

\begin{lstlisting}
print "Hello world"
\end{lstlisting}

\fontencoding{LY1}\selectfont
\begin{lstlisting}
print "Hello world"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]